# How to get another widget from the same layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

My code is as follow. I just don't wanna set an id to my EditText and findViewById. Because I'm building dynamic ui. So static id is useless for me. I'm now trying to get the EditText from the linearLayout but it didn't work yet. Any idea ?

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
LayoutParams cbLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    locationLayout.setLayoutParams(cbLayoutParams);
                    locationLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

EditText edtText = new EditText(this);
edtText.setEnable(false);
edtText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(150,50));
linearLayout.addView(edtText);

Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("say hello");
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v){
         EditText edt = null;
         for(int i=0; i<linearLayout.getChildCount();i++){
            Class<?> c = (Class<?>) linearLayout.getChildAt(i).getClass();
            if(c.getName().equals("android.widget.EditText")){
                edt = (EditText) linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
            }
         }
         edt.setText("hello");
     }
});
```

Comment: huh huh, it didn't work. I tried so in the first place. If that easy, I won't waste my time posting the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `EditText` final.

```
final EditText edtText = new EditText(this);
```

And then you can use your final `edtText` reference inside button's `onClick`:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
LayoutParams cbLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    locationLayout.setLayoutParams(cbLayoutParams);
                    locationLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

final EditText edtText = new EditText(this);
edtText.setEnabled(false);
edtText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(150,50));
linearLayout.addView(edtText);

Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("say hello");
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v){
         edtText.setText("hello");
     }
});
```

Comment: Just test it and you will see if everything is fine:)

Comment: My problem really is I can't set tag to that edtText. When I do edtText.setTag("hello"). It says IllegalArgumentException: The key must be an application-specific resourse id. :3

Comment: I think you want to `setText` instead of `setTag`:)